# How to change label of Record types

Tags: reporting

[image]How can I change the record type label "Record Type of the new record" and remove the "Available Opportunity Record Types"Available on the left-hand side?

Comment: Please post a screenshots for better understanding

Comment: Added screenshot .kindly check.

Comment: You can change the label on the object setup screen. Iirc you cannot remove the description section without rolling your own page

Answer (score 1):

From the standard recordType selection page, you can not change the label.

Though you can create this kind recordType selection page with visualforce and display your customize label.

You can populate the recordtype list based on this following code:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> lstRT = R.getRecordTypeInfos();
for(Schema.RecordTypeInfo rt:lstRT)
{
    System.debug('RecordTypeName=' + rt.getName() + ' RecordTypeId=' + rt.getRecordTypeId());
}
```

Comment: updated code, you can use this and close this question

Comment: Can we remove the"Hide Close Date" field from the opportunity object??

Comment: You can close this question and ask a new one